# #1064 When Deleting item from Table

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, phpmyadmin

I recently upgraded to MYSQL 5. That is latest version that webhost allows. When trying to update a table or delete an entry this is the error I receive while in phpmyadmin.

Error

There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 101
STR: '
SQL: DELETE FROM `inmates` WHERE `inmates`.`counties_id` = 33 AND CONVERT(`inmates`.`link` USING utf8) = \'http://inmate1.riversidesheriff.org/iis/\' LIMIT 1

SQL query:

```
DELETE FROM inmates 
WHERE `inmates`.`counties_id` = 33 
AND CONVERT(`inmates`.`link` USING utf8) = \'http://inmate1.riversidesheriff.org/iis/\' 
LIMIT 1
```

MySQL said:

> Documentation  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '\'http://inmate1.riversidesheriff.org/iis/\' LIMIT
>   1' at line 1

and here is the query

```
SELECT * FROM `inmates` WHERE 1
```

any help is greatly appreciated
thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify if you are specifically typing a query and issuing it, or entirely using phpMyAdmin GUI (checkbox, form submit, etc)?

Comment: Are you really using backticks in your SQL statements?

Comment: In MySQLand, backticks fall from the sky and land on your queries :)

Comment: JC, i am entirely in phpMyAdmin

Comment: ypercube, does that mean that the syntax of the query is wrong? is that what you are trying to tell me?

Comment: No, the syntax is fine. Too many backticks can be harmful for your eyes and I guess many people don't like them.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the backslash before the single-quotes: they are not required.

By that I mean, change this:

```
\'http://inmate1.riversidesheriff.org/iis/\'
```

To this:

```
'http://inmate1.riversidesheriff.org/iis/'
```

Comment: JC, i am using the GUI in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Kieren, the URL is the only thing in the table, there are not back slashes or single quotes....

Comment: Your query, included in the question, has backslashes.  They are not valid and should be removed.  This line right here from your question: AND CONVERT(`inmates`.`link` USING utf8) = \'http://inmate1.riversidesheriff.org/iis/\'

Comment: Kieren, when I go to either edit the item or delete it, there are no back slashes. Remember, i am using  a GUI type program (phpMyAdmin) to edit this, so the url is simply http://inmate1.riversidesheriff.org/iis/